# Outputting a series of numbers into a csv file in one cell as string in python

Tags: python, string, csv

I am trying to write a series of numbers into a csv file. but all numbers should be in one cell and separated with `","`.

```
seq = str((554, 551, 553, 563, 562, 575, 581, 560, 576, 577, 578, 579))

with open('VROutput.csv', "wb") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile,  delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerow(('Game', 'Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour', 'Minute', 'Open Table', 'Opening Order'))
    for s, t, i in set((s, t, i) for s, t, i, p, n, k in combo):
         writer.writerow((i, '2014', '8', day, t, '00', quicksum(x[s, (int(t)), i, p, n, k].x for s, t, i, p, n, k   
combo.select(s, t, i, p, '*', '*')), seq))
```

In the output file `i` the last cell in each row is `seq` but I don't want to see any brackets or parentheses  or anything around the numbers. I want to see `554, 551, 553, 563, 562, 575, 581, 560, 576, 577, 578, 579` printed out in the last cell of each row.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> ','.join(map(str,(554, 551, 553, 563, 562, 575, 581, 560, 576, 577, 578, 579)))
'554,551,553,563,562,575,581,560,576,577,578,579'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure your exact desired output, and I simplified your posted code a bit to make it run, but if you define `seq` as a list and do this:

```
import csv

seq= [554,551,553,563,562,575,581,560,576,577,578,579]
writer=csv.writer(open('testFile.csv','wb'))
for i in range(3):
        outLists = [[i,'2014','8',1,4,'00'],[str(val) for val in seq]]
        outFin = [item for subList in outLists for item in subList]
        writer.writerow(outFin)
```

You will get an output without *any* quotes or brackets like this:

```
0,2014,8,1,4,00,554,551,553,563,562,575,581,560,576,577,578,579
1,2014,8,1,4,00,554,551,553,563,562,575,581,560,576,577,578,579
2,2014,8,1,4,00,554,551,553,563,562,575,581,560,576,577,578,579
```

However [wwii](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2823755/wwii)'s answer will put quotes around your final cell, which may look wrong to you in a text editor, but will make software such as MS Excel, create a final cell like you seem to want.  This will look like this in a text editor:

```
0,2014,8,1,4,00,"554,551,553,563,562,575,581,560,576,577,578,579"
1,2014,8,1,4,00,"554,551,553,563,562,575,581,560,576,577,578,579"
2,2014,8,1,4,00,"554,551,553,563,562,575,581,560,576,577,578,579"
```

which was generated by this code:

```
import csv

seq = ','.join(map(str,(554, 551, 553, 563, 562, 575, 581, 560, 576, 577, 578, 579)))
'554,551,553,563,562,575,581,560,576,577,578,579'
writer=csv.writer(open('testFile.csv','wb'))
for i in range(3):
        withQuotes = (i,'2014','8',1,4,'00',seq)
        writer.writerow(withQuotes)
```